# Google cloud authorization with credentials.json

Tags: python

newbie question here about python django deployment.

I have a ready django server that I am ready to host. It uses google vision api for text extraction. The problem is that whenever i tried to use it after successfully hosting it, I'm getting this error about authorisation.

```
Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc for more information.
```

When I had this on my local computer I had installed the CLI on the computer but on the hosting it will be just django without CLI client.
I've got my credentials.json file from google cloud but I have no idea how to do authorization when running my code..

Looked in documentation but only thing that found is how to get credential setup but not how to use it for authorisation. maybe i'm looking bad but would like to have some help if possible..

```
{
  "client_id": "",
  "client_secret": "",
  "quota_project_id": "",
  "refresh_token": "",
  "type": "authorized_user"
}
```

credentials file without values here..